# Any elegant solution to ambiguous references?

Tags: c++

There are a lot of ambiguous references occured in my code. I have to remove "using namespace x" codes and change every "something" to "x::something"... Is there any shortcut or elegant solution?

Yes I know, I won't use "using namespace" again :)

Comment: The elegant solution is to use namespaces, their whole existance is to prevent name clashes... What I personally tend to do, mostly when working with boost is shorten namespace names, for example: `namespace bfs = boost::filesystem;` and then I can do `bfs::wtv` after.

Comment: Stop using `using`.  be explicit.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I guess that this is exactly what he is trying to do.

Comment: You can keep the using clause and disambiguate the ambiguous references only.

Comment: First, move all the `using namespace x` to function bodies and see what happens. (You will need to change interface beforehand, but that's life.) Also, `sed s/fun/x::fun/g` is your friend.

Comment: @Borgleader thank you for your suggestion it will be useful, but not the solution of the current situation.

Comment: @NathanOliver I won't anymore. But the current situation is this. I have to change a lot of line of code to make correction. That is the reason why am I askin this kind of question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

instead of using:

```
using namespace std; // all std
```

You could just specifically disambiguate:

```
using std::cout, std::cin, std::endl; // specific references from std
```

Comment: Good, that will be useful. Is there anyway to do something like: "using namespace std; using not std::cout"?

Comment: I am afraid that you can not: [**Excluding a class from a namespace (c++)**](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/503495-excluding-a-class-from-a-namespace-c/). But this `using namespace std; using x::cout;` (where `x` is your alternative `cout`'s class) should not be a problem. @wArtist